# Binding class to ListView data template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I am trying to bind a ListView with a Model List. The xaml is as  -

```
<ListView Name="lvProductBinding" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="434" Margin="10,144,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="909">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander Header="{Binding ProductNo}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="967,153,-912,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="895" Height="224" IsExpanded="False">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="195" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="895" Margin="0,0,-2,0">
                        <Label  Content="{Binding ProductDescription}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="181" Height="27" />
                        <Label  Content="{Binding VendorName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="181" Height="27" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In mu xaml.cs I am doing this inside the constructor -

```
List<ProductDetailsModel> products;
        products = new List<ProductDetailsModel>();

        ProductDetailsModel objProductDetailsModel = new ProductDetailsModel();
        objProductDetailsModel.VendorProductInventory = new VendorProductInventory() { ProductNo = "XS-3487", ProductDescription = "Perfume", VendorName = "JohnDoe" };
        products.Add(objProductDetailsModel);

        objProductDetailsModel = new ProductDetailsModel();
        objProductDetailsModel.VendorProductInventory = new VendorProductInventory() { ProductNo = "TT-23487", ProductDescription = "Shoes", VendorName = "Richard Gere" };
        products.Add(objProductDetailsModel);

        objProductDetailsModel = new ProductDetailsModel();
        objProductDetailsModel.VendorProductInventory = new VendorProductInventory() { ProductNo = "VFG-33487", ProductDescription = "Socks", VendorName = "Tom Cruise" };
        products.Add(objProductDetailsModel);

        lvProductBinding.ItemsSource = products;
```

where the ProductDetailsModel class is defined as -

```
public class ProductDetailsModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ProductDetailsModel()
    {

    }

    private VendorProductInventory _vendorProductInventory;
    public VendorProductInventory VendorProductInventory
    {
        get
        {
            return _vendorProductInventory;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_vendorProductInventory != value)
            {
                _vendorProductInventory = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }


}
```

Can someone please advise as to what I am doing wrong here.

Eagerly waiting for a reply.
Thanks,
Saket

Comment: Please read the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN to learn how to implement this interface correctly because you are not currently doing so. Also, you need to explain the problem that you're having.

Comment: Are you going to let us know what your problem is? Now *we* are 'eagerly waiting *your* reply'.

Comment: Apologies for delay, had to step out. My problem is that it is not displaying in the listView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with the code you posted.

First, as Sheridan noted, your implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged is wrong, automatic updates to the data in the ListView won't work until it is correct.

Second, all of the bindings listed in your XAML file don't have matching public properties in the ProductDetailsModel class. More than likely your ListView is being populated and all the bindings are failing (you should see exceptions for this in the VS output window at runtime). Your bindings, as written, should look like:

```
{Binding Path=VendorProductInventory.ProductNo}
```

Comment: Yeah the INotifyPropertyChanged, I will set. (I had created this as a sample file to reduce complexity- hence copy pasted). Is that hindering the display ? The second part, you pointed out, I have implemented it, still not binding. Could I be missing something else.

Comment: Eliminate the following from your Expander tag:
Margin="967,153,-912,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="895" Height="224"

You should see some output, though the formatting still seems to need a lot of work.

Comment: Having INotifyPropertyChanged wrong will not hinder initial display, but without it, changes to the object in code behind will not be propagated to the UI.

Comment: Thank you very much...The Margin thing was utterly silly of me.